# Equivalent of oracle function SYS_GUID() in DB2 LUW?

Tags: oracle, db2, uuid

Hello I'm using DB2/LINUXX8664 and I would like to know the equivalent of the oracle function SYS_GUID() function in DB2 LUW.

```
create table ab(
uuid varchar2(36) default sys_guid());
```

The Code above is for Oracle, do we have this built-in function in DB2?

Comment: Db2-LUW at currently supported versions does not have a direct equivalent to Oracle SYS_GUID(). If the purpose of your uuid column is to act as a surrogate key then consider using instead an identity column. Otherwise you can write a User Defined Function in any supported language (e.g. java) which returns a UUID as long as the output matches your column datatype - although it won't be usable in DDL via the DEFAULT clause. Google for examples of such functions, because this is a FAQ.

Comment: Ok I got it.  Thx Mao for you support !

Comment: @Elmo FYI a SYS_GUID should be stored as  a 16 byte raw  and not a 32 byte varchar2 as you may run into some issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Db2 LUW and IBMi both have [GENERATE_UNIQUE()](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=sf-generate-unique)

But it returns a 13 byte binary string instead of the 16 byte binary string Oracle's function  does.

In addition, Db2 doesn't support the use of a function in the `DEFAULT` clause for a column in a table definition.